# "Winter sales" vs. "winter discounts" vs. "winter offers"

Tags: word-choice, nouns

We have a service, and we provide season discounts at this time of the year. Which of the following is the most preferable?

> - The winter sales started at "Company X"!
> - The winter discounts started at "Company X"!
> - The winter offers started at "Company X"!

Comment: All of them are fine [including "offers"], but they all need the auxiliary ***have*** as Bill has commented. In that respect, they are all as *incorrect* as each other :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say "Winter {sales / discounts [CHOOSE ONE]} have begun at Company X!"

Answer (score 1):

Any of these forms could be used and in advertising material you might expect to find examples of all three.

*The winter sales* is the least specific and you could say

> - During the winter sales, Company X has great offers and deep discounts.
> - The winter offers started at Company X with great discounts during our seasonal sale.

Comment: That's correct and I agree, but the space I have to place that phraze is too short, so I cannot place that long phraze. Anyway @Fortiter, thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 1):

All of those are understandable. I would note that in some jurisdictions you cannot legally call an event a "sale" or a price a "discount" unless you've been selling the same item at a higher price for a minimum amount of time. If this applies where you are, and if you haven't been selling the same items, then only the last is allowed (you can have a "special offer" or an "offer" any time, as that just says that it's a good price, not a better price than normally available in the same place).

Comment: I don't think UK law specifically singles out particular words (such as *sale, discount*). It's just that if the retailer presents *any* "special price" in the context of it being less than the "standard price", the higher price must have been charged by the retailer for *at least 28 days within the last 6 months*. This law kicks in whenever the customer might reasonably suppose from the retailer's phrasing that he's buying something for less than the normal price, if the retailer makes a point of actually saying what that normal price is/was.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You can say something is an offer because it's a sale (covered by such rules), or an offer because it's below the RRP, or an offer because somewhere else is selling it higher and so on. You need to be able to back up whichever claim is made.

Comment: The concept of RRP was discredited in the UK decades ago by the ludicrous values listed for Japanese hi-fi equipment, so no-one could mount a successful prosecution on the grounds of an artificially inflated RRP. But for the rest, you've essentially captured the "spirit" of UK law - *you need to be able to back up whichever claim is made*. My point is that currently the law very specifically includes that *at least 28 days within the last 6 months* point, but it doesn't distinguish between particular words (such as *sale, discount, offer*).